# delete cart since cronjob in Magento

Tags: magento, cron

Hi i thy to delete all cart of customer, i don´t get it since cornjob, i put this in a controller and work fine

```
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/Mage.php');
$app = Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear(); // Try this

foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save(); // or try that
}

header('Location: /'); // send them back to root (or /magento/ if stored in a subfolder)
```

or

```
foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}
```

but don´t work in a cron. 
who is the problem?

Comment: Same issue, How did you done this . In my cash i want to flush cart for every 30 minutes.

Comment: i don´t resolve this problem, the case is that the cart is saved in the session of the customer, then since a controller for example you can remove this session, but since a cronjob don´t have session of customer associated. Can you try to remove the tables of the quotes????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cronjobs are not run from within a single user's session, so calls like `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')` will not retrieve a user's cart. You'll need to invoke each user's particular cart in order to clear it from cron.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: You could give it a try, but I'm guessing that you'd have stock issues down the road. That's a pretty simple solution to test in a dev environment, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Mage::getModel('sales/observer')->cleanExpiredQuotes();

This is already a cron schedule function. Go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> checkout -> Shopping Cart settings and set "Quote Lifetime (days)" as per your requirement.

This will clear already processed order cart entries. To remove all cart entries (Processed/unprocessed) Just override the above observer function and

replace
$quotes->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 0);

with

$quotes->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array(1,0));

Hope this helps!

Comment: "sales_clean_quotes" cron job title is never exist untill now in "cron_schedule" table.